# Why does Silverlight 5 not stop my debugging session when I close the browser window?

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, debugging, silverlight-5.0

When debugging a Silverlight 3 or 4 application with Visual Studio, the debugging session stopped when I closed the browser window.  This was true with VS 2008, 2010, and 2012.

With Silverlight 5 runtime, my debugging session stays open after I close the browser window, and I have to explicitly stop debugging.

I've used by IE8 and IE9 experiencing the same behavior.

Anyone know why this is and how I can revert back to the original behavior?

Comment: Are you using Internet Explorer? I've seen that behavior (also with SL4) with Firefox for instance.

Comment: Yes, internet explorer.  Happens in both IE8 and IE9.

Comment: Have you installed the Developer Runtime, not the consumer version?

Comment: I can confirm it works fine on my PCs. Have you checked the debugging settings of your web project?

Comment: @jv42 - Ah, Developer runtime.  Let me check that...

Comment: @jv42 - nope, didn't make a difference.  turns out i already had the silverlight 5 developer runtime (but I re-installed just to be certain)

Answer (score 0):

I run into this kinda problems all the time. Worse if IE does not clear cache and still loading old version of XAP **even if you made** a small change in code. So the solution I found it to install Fiddler2 run it with VS and everytime I start debugging (or even in the middle of debugging) I switch to Fiddler2 and press Ctrl+Shift+X (Clear cache). This action guarantee to clear cache and load IE with actual SL app that you debugging.  May be there's a way to automate it but it suits me for now...

Is this was helpful for you ?

Comment: I'm not so sure my issue has to do with loading from the cache.  When I debug an SL project, it correctly executes the most recent XAP.  The problem is when I close the browser, the debugger stays alive when the behavior with SL4 was to stop immediately.  Even if this were the case, having to use Fiddler is even *more* steps than simply stopping the debugging session manually.